# How to compute Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for the best way to compute some data.

i have a table as shown below:

```
|User| Operation |   Date   |  Hint   |
---------------------------------------
|us1 |    Add    |2014-06-25|some text|
|us1 |    Add    |2014-07-01|some text|
|us1 |   Delete  |2014-07-12|some text|
|us1 |   Modify  |2014-07-14|some text|
|us1 |   Update  |2014-07-15|some text|
|us2 |    Add    |2014-07-17|some text|
|us2 |    Add    |2014-07-01|some text|
|us2 |   Modify  |2014-07-14|some text|
|us2 |   Delete  |2014-07-14|some text|
|us2 |   Update  |2014-07-14|some text|
|us2 |   Update  |2014-07-14|some text|
|us2 |   Update  |2014-07-14|some text|
|us2 |   Update  |2014-07-14|some text|
|us2 |   Update  |2014-07-14|some text|
```

I want to write a SQL query to get a table like below:

```
|User|Add|Modify|Update|Delete|
-------------------------------
|us1 | 2 |  1   |  1   |  0   |
|us2 | 2 |  1   |  5   |  1   |
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for. It uses conditional computation.

```
SELECT 
[User],
[Add] = SUM(CASE [Operation] WHEN 'Add' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
[Modify] = SUM(CASE [Operation] WHEN 'Modify' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
[Update] = SUM(CASE [Operation] WHEN 'Update' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
[Delete] = SUM(CASE [Operation] WHEN 'Delete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM [tablename]
GROUP BY [User]
ORDER BY [User] ASC
```